# Cache discriminator viable approach in web pages

Tags: javascript, html, caching

In the project i have developed till now, i usually add a random number to each request of data or file related to the project.
I have to specify that the projects i am talking about are web application, and cache discriminator is not applied to third party library (eg : angular) but only to my js files and ajax calls.

The idea work fine but i wonder why i can't ask to the servere which is it's version, and use this number as cache discriminator (instead of a random number that will change on each request).
I would like to proceed in that way only for the "file discriminator" and not for ajax call discriminator (ajax request should never be cached, file request can be cached if the application does not change).

In that way my custom javascript files can be cached by browser and be valid until i publish a new version.
Now i don't know if it's a lack of my knolwedge or what, but i never heard about that tecnique, and i would like to know if there are some loophole i am not seeing (and that's may be why no one adopted this approach).

Comment: You could use the "if modified since" cache control header. In a couple of my projects I've injected (at build time) the current revision information into the HTML (the `<script>` tags) to tie the version direction to the revision control system.

Comment: The "random number at the end of request" is *very* old way of cache busting. It still works and technically isn't obsolete, however, there are much better techniques available for years. Setting the cache headers on the server will instruct the browser when to expire the cache or to not cache some resource at all. Technically, browsers can ignore the cache headers but I'm not sure many (if any) commercial ones do. Furthermore, browsers can do a preflight request to verify whether to re-fetch something. Your approach seems like at least partially reinventing this mechanism.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks i will dig into this cache headers, that's new to me. Thanks again for point it out

Comment: @VLAZ everything you wrote is correct, *however* the advantage of well-done "primitive" cache control is that it avoids the need for any additional HTTP request when the cached version should be used. That's why I did it with our SVN version number for the deployed application, and via build-time automation: to make it reliable and invisible to me (the developer).